# ArcGIS Label Manager 10.2 takes 20-30 seconds to load

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, arcgis-10.2

Why does label manager take 20-30 seconds to load? I am on 10.2 with a SSD and 24gb of RAM.

Does anyone else have issue loading the label manager in ArcMap? Is there any way to speed this process up?

It almost seems like the longer ArcMap has been installed, the longer this process takes.

I just loaded a shapefile with 8 simple polyline features and it took 20+ seconds to load the label manager.

I should also note that this has been hapening for me since 10.1. I also did a fresh install of my OS and 10.2 a couple months ago

Comment: Try with a new .mxd?

Comment: maybe describe your data layers and label schema. I have a pretty complex document open and label manager took about 2-3 seconds to open. not lightning fast but without a better description of "forever" probably faster than yours is taking.

Comment: I Agree with @BradNesom I haven't had a problem with it even with huge statewide datasets and I only have 16gb RAM

Comment: @BradNesom - Just added some more info

Comment: @Mapperz - I have tried with new, old and no mxds

Comment: 8GB of ram and a blazing SSD here, and it comes up instantly. I had multiple county-wide datasets that take longer to draw than to open the manager.

Comment: weird... seems like a bug then? i am hoping someone else has the same issue(s)

Answer (score 1):

I have many fonts installed on my OS. About 1500 really.

Apparently other people have had slow performance with many fonts installed
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/8386-Desktop-ArcGIS-10-Really-Slow/page3